# Confirmation of OR (||) usage in a return command

Tags: php

I've come across some interesting usage of the || operator in a return command, and would appreciate it if someone could confirm exactly what is going on (if I understand it, I can use it myself in the future)

The code is

```
    return (
        empty($neededRole) ||
        strcasecmp($role, 'admin') == 0 ||
        strcasecmp($role, $neededRole) == 0
    );
```

$neededRole and $role are either null, 'admin' or 'manager'

I'm reading it as:
If `$neededRole` is empty, no further checks are needed. Return true (and stop checking)
If `($role == 'admin')` then allow access, no matter the required role. Return true (and stop checking)
if `($role == $neededRole)` then allow access. Return true (and stop checking)

I'm guessing that upon reaching a 'true' that the checking stops, and if it reached the end of the line without having a 'true', it will default to false.

Am I close to the mark?

Comment: Forgot to add, if there is a name for this technique, I'd love to know to read up on it further

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. This is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  The final return value if all the conditions evaluate to false will be `false || false || false` which is false.

As a side note this also works with the `&&` operator, but it stops evaluation when the first expression results in a `false` value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right

See an example in [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

```
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit
$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```